# Как спроектировать сайт по поиску работы?

Tags: php, yii2, веб-программирование, проектирование

Доброго времени суток. Делаю сайт для поиска работы, разделил его на два модуля, модуль работника и модуль работодателя в каждом модуле есть поиск, собственно вопрос в каком модуле должен быть какой поиск? По сути работодателю нужно искать работников но если поиск работников реализовать в модуле работодателя думаю получится не правильно, как лучше сделать?

Comment: Вопрос настолько обширный, что в ответе пришлось бы изложить целую статью рассуждений.